# In tropo which link i should give for "What URL powers your app?" option while creating new application with Tropo WebAPI?

Tags: node.js, tropo

In my application i need to use tropo with node.js.I installed tropo webapi using npm and i added code to send sms,make call but i don't know how to receive the incoming text and call.Also i don't know how to mention my url in their "What URL powers your app?" option.Because i don't have url now i'm doing it locally.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like it doesn't work locally: https://www.tropo.com/docs/webapi/using_tunnlr_reverse_ssh.htm

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give a local URL, because then tropo website will not be able to access this URL. You will have to host your application on the internet and provide this public URL to tropo.